# Regex to extract both video id or playlist id from youtube url

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I would like to know how to extract youtube video id or playlist id depending upon the url using a single regex expression. The regex should also ensure that the domain is youtube.com
Here are some of the results I need:

**Extract Playlist ID For**

```
    https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r
    www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r
    http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r
    https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r
```

**Extract Video ID For**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqMfRi2gJok&index=1&list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqMfRi2gJok
http://youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM 
http://youtube.com/embed/cCnrX1w5luM
http://youtube.com/v/cCnrX1w5luM
https://www.youtube.com/v/cCnrX1w5luM
www.youtube.com/v/cCnrX1w5luM
youtube.com/v/cCnrX1w5luM
```

These are just example urls only. I need to extract respective ID's for all possible youtube link structures.

In short extract video id and if it is absent obtain playlist id.

Comment: I suggest first capturing `v` then capture `list`. Because then you can't decide which string is which.

Comment: What do you mean by single regex? both playlist and video id and all forms?

Comment: @terces907 Yes, I need a single expression to extract for all url structure

Comment: Mainly, you want vdo_id right? but if no vdo_id you want playlist_id instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is explicitly has two patterns

**The first:**

```
^.*?(?:v|list)=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

For any urls which have explicit attribute, or you can say they have `=` symbol in url.

**Explanation**

`^.*?(?:v|list)=`: Any string till word `v=` or `list=` which here we prefer `v` over `list`,

`(.*?)(?:&|$)`: Any string which ended by `&` symbol or ending line symbol `$` which here we prefer `&` over `$`.

**The second:**

```
^(?:(?!=).)*\/(.*)$
```

For any url which don't have attribute or there is no `=` symbol in url.

**Explanation**

`^(?:(?!=).)*\/`: Any string which don't have `=` symbol (here handle by the negative lookahead `(?!=)`) till `/` symbol,

`(.*)$`: Any string till the end of line.

Combine them into one regex we get

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?.*?(?:v|list)=(.*?)(?:&|$)|^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?(?:(?!=).)*\/(.*)$
```

here,

`(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?` is added to handle various form of [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)'s url

and this should help you get what you want

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hN3tJ6/2)

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** This question, questioner want to extract `id` from [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) which he prefer "video id" over "playlist id".

Comment: It also extracts from xyz.com/v/cCnrX1w5luM which is not expected.

Comment: You should tell me beforehand. Please add this requirement into your question.

Comment: @jollykoshy This answer failed to capture the list:`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqMfRi2gJok&index=1&list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r`

Comment: @terces907 Yours failed to capture the list:`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqMfRi2gJok&index=1&list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4Rg‌​qA76_Gv52fGA0909r`

Comment: @DanielCheung He prefer `video_id` over `list_id`, I'd mentioned already on my explanation.

Comment: It fail if you have a Youtube video ID and playlist. it won't find de playlist ID. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tmd-ClpJxA&list=RDQMyFModNyxXx8

Answer (score 4):

https://regex101.com/r/mI3qY9/4

This regex assumes you are giving it a legitimate Youtube link. This grabs all the `v` and `lists` together:

```
/(?:(?:\?|&)(?:v|list)=|embed\/|v\/|youtu\.be\/)((?!videoseries)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g
```

**Breakdown:**

```
/
(?:                         //non-capturing group
  (?:\?|&)(?:v|list)=       //? or & following a v or list
  |                         //or
  embed\/                   //embed/
  |                         //or
  v\/                       //v/            
  |                         //or
  youtu\.be\/               //youtu.be/
)
(
  (?!videoseries)           //will not capture "videoseries"
  [a-zA-Z0-9_]*             //capture any alphabet digits or underscore that follows afterwards
)          
/g                          //global
```

But you may not be able to tell which is `v` and which is `list`, so,

This only grabs the `v`:

```
/(?:(?:\?|&)v=|embed\/|v\/|youtu\.be\/)((?!videoseries)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g
```

This only grabs the `list`:

```
/(?:(?:\?|&)list=)((?!videoseries)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g
```

**This only grabs YouTube `v`s:**

```
/(?:youtube\.com.*(?:\?|&)(?:v)=|youtube\.com.*embed\/|youtube\.com.*v\/|youtu\.be\/)((?!videoseries)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g
```

**Only YouTube `list`s:**

```
/(?:youtube\.com.*(?:\?|&)(?:list)=)((?!videoseries)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g
```

This is basically the same but adding `youtube\.com.*` too to the regex. It won't grab e.g. `http://example.com/v/abc`

https://regex101.com/r/mI3qY9/5

**Explanation:**

```
youtube\.com.*          //Matches youtube.com and any multiple characters followed
```

Comment: The regex also matches 'videoseries'. How to avoid that? Moreover the regex fails to check if the domain is youtube.com itself.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being familiar with Youtube links, bit is "videoseries" not a video?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r   should yield only PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r

Comment: All done except this url which extracts playlist id where video id is expected https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqMfRi2gJok&index=1&list=PLuC2HflhhpLGQ4RgqA76_Gv52fGA0909r

Comment: @jollykoshy I'll look at it.

Comment: @jollykoshy Can you really not separate it into 2 regexes? Because I really can't think of a way to combine it into a regex. Even if that's possible, it would be **extremely** long and slow and not worth it.

Comment: It's miss one case i found when the playlist contain "-" character so it be this: 
  /(?:(?:\?|&)(?:v|list)=|embed\/|v\/|youtu\.be\/)((?!videoseries)[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
/\?(?:v|list)=(\w*)/g
```

You can use regexp or (|)

You can test and see it here:

https://regex101.com/r/mI3qY9/2

[image]

**UPDATE**

I update the regexp (Thank you for the comment to capture underscore), and make the first group non-capture

**Update to also capture: youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM**

*/(?:\?v=|\?list=|be/)(\w*)/g*

https://regex101.com/r/mI3qY9/6

Comment: you may turn the first capturing group to non-capturing group. And it's better if you use `\w+` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Comment: Is the underscore a part of the list string? Because your regex didn't capture that.

Comment: I change it now it is capture it

Comment: It doesn't extract for http://youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM . Sorry for not mentioning it before.