# How to format a user-provided YouTube URL for iFrame embedding using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, src, youtube-iframe-api

I have a website, and I want to allow users to input a YouTube link for a playlist/video into a field, press a button, and have an iFrame popup playing the linked content. I'm fetching the link with JavaScript from the `<input>` field and sending it to the iFrame's `src=""` attribute, as such:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function embedMusic() {
        let musicUrl = document.getElementById("link").value;
    
        $("#music-player").show();
        $("#music-player").attr("src", musicUrl);
    }
</script>

<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="link">Music link:</label>
    <input id="link" type="url" name="url" placeholder="https://www..." autocomplete="off">
    <input onclick="embedMusic()" type="button" value="Embed">
</form>
<iframe id="music-player" frameborder="0" title="Music player"></iframe>

</html>
```

The `src=""` URL formatting for YouTube playlists and videos is different, specifically:

`src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID"` embeds the video defined in the VIDEOID section.

`src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLAYLISTID"` embeds the playlist defined in the PLAYLISTID section.

However, the URL that the user copies from his browser will be different than the one supposed to be used in the `src=""` field:

Sample copied video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID

Sample copied playlist URL: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAYLISTID

So my JavaScript code has to:

1. Identify if the provided URL is a video or a playlist
2. Format it correctly for the `src=""` field depending on the embed type

And imma be honest I have no idea of how to begin doing this. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to extract both video id or playlist id from youtube url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295157/regex-to-extract-both-video-id-or-playlist-id-from-youtube-url)

Comment: @DanielBeck that would be an example of extracting the content's ID by identifying if it's a video or playlist, but I'd still need to format and plug that ID into the correct iframe src="" structure.

Comment: Once you've got the ID it's just a matter of concatenating it into a string with the rest of the url.  If you mean you're not able to differentiate between playlists and videos, see Daniel Cheung's answer on that page

Comment: @DanielBeck I already solved this using a dumb method but it works, thanks for the help anwyays though!